# amplify.store quota exceeded on iPad 1

Tags: javascript, session-storage, amplifyjs

I'm using AmplifyJS Store in a JQuery plugin I'm developing.

While I was testing it I noticed that on First-generation iPad [1] I get an alert that says `amplify.store quota exceeded` anytime I change orientation and refresh the page (when it loads first time nothing happens). This plugin sets about 30 sessionStorage variables, virtually all strings, and total size for all the variables combined can't be more than 80Kb.

I'm using primarily sessionStorage in my plugin (see the following pseudo code):

`amplify.store.sessionStorage( string key, mixed value);`

When I use the plugin on the iPad 2 and higher I don't see the alert.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.

It appears that when you reset the stored value to null before setting it again, the problem is solved (below is the pseudo code):

```
amplify.store.sessionStorage( string key, null);
amplify.store.sessionStorage( string key, mixed value);
```

I hope it helps!

Cheers.